# Is it possible for (current-buffer) not to return some buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've tried to write a simple test (kill-buffer-test.el):

```
:; exec emacs -Q --script "$0" -- "$@"

(setq debug-on-error t)

(setq n 0)
(dolist (idx (buffer-list))
  (message "%d '%s' %s" n idx (buffer-list))
  (setq n (+ 1 n))
  (message "result: %s cb='%s'\n" (kill-buffer idx) (current-buffer)))
```

And run it:

```
$ ./kill-buffer-test.el
0 '*scratch*' (*scratch*  *Minibuf-0* *Messages*  *code-conversion-work*  *load*)
result: t cb='*Messages*'

1 ' *Minibuf-0*' ( *Minibuf-0* *Messages*  *code-conversion-work*  *load*)
result: nil cb='*Messages*'

2 '*Messages*' ( *Minibuf-0* *Messages*  *code-conversion-work*  *load*)
result: t cb='*scratch*'

3 ' *code-conversion-work*' ( *Minibuf-0*  *code-conversion-work*  *load* *scratch* *Messages*)
result: t cb='*scratch*'

4 ' *load*' ( *Minibuf-0*  *load* *scratch* *Messages*)
result: t cb='*scratch*'

Selecting deleted buffer
$ echo $?
255
```

Notice that `*Minibuf-0*` buffer wasn't killed (why?), `*scratch*` was resurrected, and emacs exited with a strange error message.

So, should I worry that (current-buffer) may fail? And if I should, how to test that? (current-buffer) will raise an error or will just return nil?

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `version`
GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit) of 2013-02-08 on linux.9bf016

Comment: I also noticed today that I wasn't able to `(kill-buffer " *Minibuf-1*")` for some reason not know to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to worry: `(current-buffer)` can't fail (Emacs would crash and burn if it ever did).
`*scratch*` as well as a few other internal buffers get re-generated as/when needed.